# respondsToSelector always return false

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following four files,

HttpClient.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface HttpClient : NSObject{
    ....
}

   ....
    @end

@protocol HttpClientDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)handleReceivedData: (NSArray*)results returnArrayOrDic:(NSNumber *)returnArrayOrDic;
- (void)handleConnectionError: (NSURLConnection *)connection error:(NSError*)error;
@end
```

HttpClient.m

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"*********************************************");
    ....
    NSLog(@"delegate in callee:%@", passedInDelegate);
    if (passedInDelegate == nil) NSLog(@"passedInDelegate is NIL");
    BOOL flag = [passedInDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData:)];
    NSLog(flag ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    flag = [passedInDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData)];
    NSLog(flag ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    if([passedInDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData:)]){
       NSLog(@"handleReceivedData is founded");
      [passedInDelegate performSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData:) withObject:jsonObject withObject:returnArrayOrDic];
    }

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");

}
```

ProductListViewController.h

```
@interface ProductListViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,HttpClientDelegate>
 ....

/*this is handle the call back*/

- (void)handleReceivedData: (NSArray*)results returnArrayOrDic:(NSNumber *)returnArrayOrDic;
- (void)handleConnectionError: (NSURLConnection *)connection error:(NSError*)error;

@end
```

ProductListViewController.m

```
/*callback of the httpClient*/

- (void)handleReceivedData: (NSArray*)results returnArrayOrDic:(NSNumber *)returnArrayOrDic{
    NSLog(@"********************");
    NSLog(@"handleReceivedData has been called");
    ....
}
```

From the logs printed out,

```
 - 2014-09-24 01:09:20.913 [298:60b] delegate in callee:<ProductListViewController: 0x1467d860> 
 - 2014-09-24 01:09:20.914 [298:60b] No     
 - 2014-09-24 01:09:20.915 [298:60b] No
```

passedInDelegate is not nil and assigned to ProductListViewController as expected. However, when callback from HttpClient to ProductListViewController, both [passedInDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData:)] and [passedInDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData)] are NO.

Appreciate for any comments?

Regards
Hammer

Comment: Does the `handleReceivedData:` method even exist? It looks like you've only implemented a method called `handleReceivedData:returnArrayOrDic:`.

Comment: Why should the object respond to a message that it doesn't implement?

Comment: For this case, how should  I change respondsToSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData:)] as the method has two paras of NSArray and NSNumber?

Comment: @Hammer What exactly are you asking? The selector for your method as it exists in your question is `handleReceivedData:returnArrayOrDic:`.

Comment: Thanks. this is exactly what I am confused. I change it to what you have suggested and modify the performSelector to [passedInDelegate performSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData:returnArrayOrDic:) withObject:jsonObject withObject:returnArrayOrDic];  it works. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the method in question is `handleReceivedData:returnArrayOrDic:`, not `handleReceivedData:`.

Change all of your references of `@selector(handleReceivedData:)` to be `@selector(handleReceivedData:returnArrayOrDic:)`.

And your whole method is way too complicated. Just do:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"*********************************************");
    ....
    NSLog(@"delegate in callee:%@", passedInDelegate);
    if ([passedInDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleReceivedData:returnArrayOrDic:)]){
        NSLog(@"handleReceivedData is founded");
        [passedInDelegate handleReceivedData:jsonObject returnArrayOrDic:returnArrayOrDic];
    }

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
}
```

There is no need to use `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`. Just call the method directly.